# Java 8 Stream convert list to map, where map key is an object derived from two fields of the list?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
class Person{
    private String first;
    private String last;
    private BigDecimal gpa;
    private int age;
}

class PersonKey{
    private String first;
    private String last;
}
```

Now I have `List<Person>` and want to convert that to `Map<PersonKey, Person>` where `PersonKey` is just the unique key value of a person. How can I achieve this with Java stream?

Comment: You're looking for `collect(Collectors.toMap(..))`.

Comment: For the map to be usable,  `PersonKey` will need to implement equals and hashCode.

Comment: @louisWasserman , I've tried that, but in ```toMap()``` I can only put one value, like ```toMap(p -> p.getFirst, p)```, but when I tried to do ```toMap(p -> new PersonKey(p.getFirst(), p.getLast(), p -> p)``` it doesn't comepile.

Comment: @WJS yes that has been implemented (thank you lombok!)

Comment: You're  missing a closing parentheses after the key.

Comment: @jconnie87 and what error does it read when it doesn't compile? why not [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67117061/edit) and share all of that in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for (presuming no two people have the same name).  The key is constructed on the fly using the getters from Person and the constructor from PersonKey.

```
Map<PersonKey, Person> map = list.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 person->new PersonKey(person.getFirst(),person.getLast()), 
                 person->person));
```

To accommodate people with the same name, you could put them in a `Map<PersonKey,List<Person>>`

```
Map<PersonKey, List<Person>> map = list.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person->new 
                              PersonKey(person.getFirst(),
                                        person.getLast())));
```

Comment: Yes you got it, I did miss the parenthesis and the compiler wasn't super obvious. newbie mistakes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could need to watch out for duplicate keys. If keys are *duplicate* then an `IllegalStateException` would be thrown.

Try this for *duplicate* keys instead:

```
// This THROWS an Exception. DO NOT DO IF DUPLICATE KEYS
// Map<PersonKey, Person> mapThrowException = list.stream().collect(
//      Collectors.toMap(p -> new PersonKey(p.first, p.last), p -> p));




// if duplicate key exists for two persons, choose the first person
Map<PersonKey, Person> properMap = 
        list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    p -> new PersonKey(p.first, p.last), 
                    p -> p,
                   (person1, person2) -> person1 ));
```

or you could use the `Function.identity()` instead provided for this purpose (for the 2nd argument).

```
Map<PersonKey, Person> properMap2 = 
         list.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                      p -> new PersonKey(p.getFirst(), p.getLast()), 
                      Function.identity(),  
                      (person1, person2) -> person1 ));
```

If the requirement is to group by key and not drop any values (in case of duplicate keys), use the `groupingBy` (as suggested by @WJS). There would be a `List<Person>` for each `PersonKey` (representing a `Person` with the same first and last names):

```
Map<PersonKey, List<Person>> properMapWithListForDuplicateKeys =
          list.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        p -> new PersonKey(p.getFirst(), p.getLast())));
```

Comment: @WJS: agreed. I'll put in a snippet later. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Make a class

The other two Answers are correct, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67117203/642706) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67117203/642706).

But if you are using the full name of the person in this way, consider writing a class. If you are using the full name like this in other places, then even more reason to make a class.

In Java 16 and later, you might choose to use the new [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature to more briefly define the class. Use a record where the primary purpose is to communicate data, transparently and immutably. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
record FullName ( String firstName , String lastName ) {}
```

So your `Person` class would look like this.

```java
class Person{
    private FullName name;
    private BigDecimal gpa;
    private int age;
}
```

Usage example.

```
Person p = new Person ( 
    new FullName( "Alice" , "Alba" ) , 
    new BigDecimal( "3.67" ) , 
    23 
) ;
```

And your map would look like this.

```java
Map< FullName , Person > map = …
```

---

By the way, using person’s name as an identifier is almost always a terrible idea in practice. That is why students are assigned student identifier numbers, employees get employee IDs, passports get an official passport number, and so on. I ignored this issue in the Answer to focus on other issues… but be forewarned.